# NodeJS Redis stream - Read previous messages

Tags: node.js, redis

Hello fellow developers,

I've recently developed a Node.js module for reading Redis streams and now I'm looking to enhance it with a couple of features. Specifically, I want to add the ability to handle missed messages and to enable multiple subscribers to a single topic with different message handling behaviors.

In essence, I aim to accomplish the following:

1. Implement a mechanism to handle missed messages in the Redis stream.
2. Allow multiple subscribers to subscribe to the same topic, with each subscriber having the option to either:

   - Read all messages published to the topic.
   - Compete with other subscribers to pick up and process a message, deleting it before other subscribers read it.

I'm seeking guidance and advice from the Node.js community on how to implement these features effectively.

Here is the link to the repository containing the current version of the module: [Simple Redis Stream Repository](https://gitlab.com/cottontailtech/simple-redis-stream)

Any insights, suggestions, or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!